# How to create album using Vimeo API

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

Is there any option to create album in Vimeo Using Vimeo API.

I have pro account.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can create Album using Vimeo API according to thier documentation please see [Vimeo Developer API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/me#/albums).

Comment: Link broken, and, link-only answers must be avoided. I downvote